# Gives all of them optional value

Tags: ios, swift, variables

Hello i have variables but gives all of them `Optional()`. How can i resolve them my codes under below.

Json append codes for `koltuklar`  `koltuklaridler`  array under below you can see

```
        for name in json as! [AnyObject] {

            let SeatName = name["SeatName"]
            let SeatDesignId = name["SeatDesignId"]
            self.koltuklar.append("\(SeatName)*\(SeatDesignId)*")

            if let blogs = json["SeatDetail"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
                for blog in blogs {

                    let TicketTypeId = blog["TicketTypeId"]
                    let TicketTypeName = blog["TicketTypeName"]
                    let Amount = blog["Amount"]

                    self.koltuklaridler.append("\(SeatDesignId)*\(TicketTypeId)*\(TicketTypeName)*\(Amount)*")


                }

            }
```

Under below you can see tableview inside codes ( That codes doing open koltuklar index path item after search id inside koltuklaridler and when found take some varibles from it )

```
var koltuklar = [""]
var koltuklaridler = [""]

if let myStrings:String! = koltuklar[indexPath.row]{

    print("\(myStrings!)")

    let myStringArrf = myStrings.componentsSeparatedByString("*")


    print("\(myStringArrf)")


    if let koltukisims:String! = String(myStringArrf[0]) {

        cell.koltukName.text = koltukisims
    }


    print(" STR - \(myStringArrf[1] as String!)")


    if let index = koltuklaridler.indexOf(myStringArrf[1] as String!) {

        let myStringdetaysecilen = koltuklaridler[index]

        print("myStringdetaysecilen \(myStringdetaysecilen)")


    }
```

Also my json file

```
[
    {
        "SeatDesignId": 16484,
        "SeatName": "A6",
        "SaloonId": 148,
        "SeatDetail": [
            {
                "TicketTypeId": 1,
                "TicketTypeName": "Okay",
                "Amount": 13
            }
        ]
    },
```

Output

```
Optional("A17")*Optional(16254)*
["Optional(\"A17\")", "Optional(16254)", ""]
STR - Optional(16254)
```

All variables output Optional i try everything but doesn't fix.

Comment: Just remove the needless type annotations (as well as the `as String!` cast). Do not annotate types at all unless the compiles tells you.

Comment: PS: In an `as` cast always the `as` takes the exclamation/question mark and never the following type.

Comment: @vadian i deleted all  as String! s but same all optional !

Comment: for your definition,  `koltuklar` is already a `String` array, you don't have to downcast it.

Comment: @WeiJay i deleted :String! inside myStrings and i deleted if and same output

Comment: How do you structure your datasource? In other words, how do your `koltuklar` come from

Comment: Then you have declared somewhere else an optional variable which affects the output. This code is supposed to throw an error in the second line without the annotation if the array is non-optional.

Comment: @WeiJay that codes inside tableview when i use that codes top side    `print("\(koltuklar[indexPath.row])")`  gives me output `Optional("D8")*Optional(16680)*`

Comment: I added also koltuklar array append json codes top side in question

Comment: The problem is you already added optional strings. Whenever you use String Interpolation `"\(...)"` make sure that all strings are unwrapped. Values read from dictionaries are **always** optional.

Comment: @vadian my codes there cell.koltukName.text why ? optional ? why myStrings optional ?

Comment: Once again: All strings (actually everything) retrieved from a dictionary are optional by definition because you get `nil` if the key does not exist.

Comment: @vadian so what is true codes vadian ? my codes there how we can fix them ?

Comment: EVERYBODY EXPLAIN EVERYTHING ! BLA , BLA BUT NOBODY GIVES FIXED CODE CHANGES !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comments, *whenever you use String Interpolation `"\(...)"` make sure that all optional strings are unwrapped. Values read from dictionaries are always optional*.

This code unwraps all optional strings

```
for name in json as! [[String:AnyObject]] {

  guard let SeatName = name["SeatName"] as? String,
        SeatDesignId = name["SeatDesignId"] as? Int else  {
      continue
  }
  self.koltuklar.append("\(SeatName)*\(SeatDesignId)*")

  if let blogs = json["SeatDetail"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
    for blog in blogs {
      if let TicketTypeId = blog["TicketTypeId"] as? Int,
           TicketTypeName = blog["TicketTypeName"]  as? String,
                   Amount = blog["Amount"]  as? Int {
        self.koltuklaridler.append("\(SeatDesignId)*\(TicketTypeId)*\(TicketTypeName)*\(Amount)*")        
      }
    }
}
```

Edit: I updated the casting to the actual types according to the JSON

Now declare both arrays as empty string arrays.

```
var koltuklar = [String]()
var koltuklaridler = [String]()
```

and remove the optional binding in the first line

```
let myStrings = koltuklar[indexPath.row]
print("\(myStrings)")
...
```

By the way: Your way to "serialize" the strings with asterisks and deserialize it in the table view is very, very clumsy and inefficient. Use a custom class or struct for the data records.

Comment: i changed that codes inside my codes but tableview dont show any item nothing

Comment: I just edited the answer because according to the JSON some of the types are numeric (`Int`) rather than `String`

Comment: now came but have issues 1: koltuklaridler dont append any item output [""] also dont search  if let index = koltuklaridler.indexOf(myStringArrf[1]) { in array

Comment: same  print(self.koltuklaridler) gives output [""] also   print("myStringdetaysecilen \(myStringdetaysecilen)") nothing

Comment: im trying to convert my codes to struct after i will update my question later i think you will be fix it easily.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are creating a string from values from dict without a if let statement so it returns an optional value:

for name in json as! [AnyObject] {

```
        if let SeatName = name["SeatName"],
           let SeatDesignId = name["SeatDesignId"] {
            self.koltuklar.append("\(SeatName)*\(SeatDesignId)*")
        }

        if let blogs = json["SeatDetail"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
            for blog in blogs {

                if let TicketTypeId = blog["TicketTypeId"],
                   let TicketTypeName = blog["TicketTypeName"],
                   let Amount = blog["Amount"] {
                   self.koltuklaridler.append("\(SeatDesignId)*\(TicketTypeId)*\(TicketTypeName)*\(Amount)*")
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: @user3441052 I updated the answer, I didn't test the code so let me know if you have problems

Comment: same dude ! dont fix

Comment: @user3441052 if you print `self.koltuklaridler` do you have the strings with optional values?

Comment: self.koltuklaridler gives output `[""]`

Comment: also i added my json comming in question

Answer (score 0):

There is a two way of operate optional.

> 1. unwrapped using "!" but in this chances of crash if value is nil.
> 2. unwrapped using term call "optional binding" using "if let" condition.

```
if let var = "assigned your optional variable"{
print(var)
}
```

You will get your variable without optional.

Comment: your answer dont fix my question

Comment: use " SeatName! " or if let newVar = seatName{ //in new variable u will found without Optional }.. hope so it will help.